# How I get the text of GtkEntry and do some other things when I click anywhere without the original GtkEntry

Tags: go, gtk3

When I click labelEntity, the focus_out_event event doesn't execute. I want to get the text and do some things (here I'm only printing it), how do I do that?

```
box,_ := gtk.BoxNew(gtk.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,0)
labelEntity,_ := gtk.EntryNew()
labelEntity.SetText(label)
labelEntity.SetVisibility(true)

box.Add(labelEntity)
box.ShowAll()
labelEntity.Connect("focus_out_event", func() {
    newLabel,_ := labelEntity.GetText()
    fmt.Println(newLabel)
})
```

I want the callback executing

Comment: It's `focus-out-event` with dashes, not underscores

Comment: By the way, Gtk should have warned you that this signal is invalid. Did you ignore it?

Comment: Hi,`focus-out-event` has the same result. I get the signal when click other buttons .That says the event can be triggered ,so I have not received warning.
Could tell me how to trigger the event when I click anywhere but the  GtkEntry.

Comment: Do you want to receive it every single time you click outside the entry?

Comment: Yes,as you said